# How to shorten object names?

Tags: outliner

I was basically wondering how you can shorten your object names automatically instead of going in and do it manually on countless of objects.

I know there is a object renaming add-on, but this only renames all the objects.

So, if anybody knows how I can just shorten the object names, I'd be very grateful!

Comment: @Mr Zak My mistake, I've corrected the question to object names. It's for exporting a *.3ds file, which doesn't allow more than a certain amount of characters in object names.

Comment: Please edit this detail into question.  Do you know how many is a certain amount?

Comment: It's ten characters. It can all be read on the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.3ds)

Comment: I basically have to shorten all objects name's in my scene, to be able to export in *.3ds properly, the batch renamer doesn't support this currently.

Answer (score 1):

This script renames all the objects and assigns a number.

```
import bpy

objects = bpy.context.scene.objects

for i in range(0, len(objects)):
    print(objects[i].name)
    objects[i].name = "object" + str(i)
    objects[i].data.name = "object" + str(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Python:

```
import bpy

objects = bpy.context.selected_objects

# number of chars you want to remove
n = 1

for obj in objects:
    new_name = obj.name[:-n]
    obj.name = new_name
```

Just copy this script to a **Text Editor** panel, select your objects and click *Run Script* (on the bottom bar).

P.S.: Keep in mind that Blender automatically adds a numeric suffix to the names if you have more than 1 object with the same name.

Comment: more on the PS, will have opposite effect re shortening names if run on for example (a not unlikely list of 3 objects):  "Cube.001, Cube.002, Cube.003"  result "Cube.00, Cube.00.001, Cube.00.002" and again "Cube.0, Cube.00.00, Cube.00.00.001".